# Android: how to get a directory list ordered by name or by date descending?

Tags: android, file

I'm able to do this:

```
    File images = new File(path);  
    File[] imageList = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
        {  
            return name.endsWith(".jpg");
        }  
    });
```

I copied from an answer of stackoverflow !

Is there a way to listFile ok kind "directory" (folder) and to list by reverse alphabetical order ?
... And by reverse date ?

Comment: I've not tryed nothing until now...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
final File[] sortedFileName = images.listFiles()

if (sortedFileName != null && sortedFileName.length > 1) {
        Arrays.sort(sortedFileName, new Comparator<File>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
             }
    });
}
```

Use `Array.sort()` to compare the name of the files.

**Edit:**
Use this code to sort by date

```
final File[] sortedByDate = folder.listFiles();

if (sortedByDate != null && sortedByDate.length > 1) {
        Arrays.sort(sortedByDate, new Comparator<File>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                return (int) ((object1.lastModified() > object2.lastModified()) ? object1.lastModified(): object2.lastModified());
             }
    });
}
```

Comment: wow !!!! And which method to compare lastmodified date ? or creation date, is identica l...

Comment: lastmodifed returns a long. So you have to use ">" inside compare

Comment: Just a modification to blackbelt code: I must remove @override ... I don't know why, but eclipse tell me to remove ... and I've removed

Comment: probably because you are targeting java 1.5

Comment: the same. check the eclipse project properties

Comment: what's the right java to target for android 4 minimum sdk ? (is an internal-only application)

Comment: The right way to do that is doing Arrays.sort(Files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE); for this instruction you will need the commons.io library from org.apache that you can download from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio201jar.htm

Comment: I tried your answer and sometimes doesn't work properly, I don't know way, but if you try the instruction that I posted, it works perfectly. For this reason I said the right way.

Comment: This is tricky. It is not working as expected at some cases. 
It is better to use compareTo than operator sign.
Just like in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249822/java-sort-files-based-on-creation-date.
It is working correctly for me.

Answer (score 3):

you can use below code. worked for me.

```
final File[] files= file.listFiles();
if (files != null && files.length > 1) {
            Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(files), new Comparator<File>() {
                public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                    long lastModifiedO1 = o1.lastModified();
                    long lastModifiedO2 = o2.lastModified();

                    return (lastModifiedO2 < lastModifiedO1) ? -1 : ((lastModifiedO1 > lastModifiedO2) ? 1 : 0);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting an exception

IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

so I used this and it worked ok:

```
Arrays.sort(filesList, new Comparator<File>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(File a, File b) {
      if(a.lastModified() < b.lastModified() )
         return 1;
      if(a.lastModified() > b.lastModified() )
         return -1;
      return 0;
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointers :

```
File.isDirectory()

File.lastModified()
```

Comment: thanks ! lastModified help me to the second half of the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer brevity:

```
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, (a, b) -> Long.compare(b.lastModified(), a.lastModified()));
```

Answer (score 1):

For sort based on file name,Add

```
object1.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
```

instead of

```
object1.getName()
```

to avoid sort issues causing by Locale changes and upper/low case filenames

```
             final File[] sortedFileName = images.listFiles();

                if (sortedFileName != null && sortedFileName.length > 1) {
                    Arrays.sort(sortedFileName, new Comparator<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                            return object1.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).compareTo(object2.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick and elegant way to sort array of files, **by date** of change is:

```
        Arrays.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
                // For descending
                // return -Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
```

To sort array of files, **by name** is:

```
        Arrays.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return f1.compareTo(f2);
                // For descending
                // return -f1.compareTo(f2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I was looking for sorting by date and your solution is wokring but it is bit slower. Is there any other way

Comment: How many files do you usually need to sort? Have you measured the speed of creating your list without sorting? Sorting files in Java, with less code I don't think you will find. Try to convert and sort them using `List` or `ArrayList` (maybe also `LinkedList`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort date wise then choose below code, and if you want name then already answer is above :)

```
File f = new File("/home/myfiles");
File [] files = f.listFiles();
Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator(){
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

    if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return +1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to order files by date of last modified in reverse mode is doing:

```
Arrays.sort(Files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
```

for this instruction you will need the commons.io library from org.apache that you can download from [here](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio201jar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using this

```
final File[] sortedByDate = folder.listFiles();

if (sortedByDate != null && sortedByDate.length > 1) {
        Arrays.sort(sortedByDate, new Comparator<File>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                return (int) ((object1.lastModified() > object2.lastModified()) ? 0: 1);
             }
    });
}
```

I return 0 and 1 insted of `lastModified()` value that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with new android, you can write inline short script to do this.
For comparing filename:

```
Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
```

For comparing modified date:

```
Arrays.sort(files, (object1, object2) -> (int) (Math.max(object1.lastModified(), object2.lastModified())));
```