# Java - How to Open the Last Updated File From a Folder that is Sorted by last modified date?

Tags: java, apache-commons, java-io

I am trying to open a csv file from the download directory in Windows. Here is the algorithm:

1. Go to the download directory in Window
2. Sort directory based on the last modify date with last updated file at the top
3. Open the last updated file

Here is the code snippet that does #1 and # 2 (obtained from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249822/java-sort-files-based-on-creation-date)): 
Code snippet is below:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileSortingTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

   Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];

       System.out.printf("File %s - %2$tm %2$te,%2$tY%n= ", file.getName(),
               file.lastModified());
  }
}
```

How do I get the last updated file into a variable and then open the file to read using Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring more in StackOverflow and this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/864/java-open-file) regarding using the Desktop class  the following I was able to use:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenAFile2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

String userdir = System.getProperty("user.home");

String dirpath2 = userdir + "\\Downloads";
File fileName = getLatestFilefromDir(dirpath2);

System.out.println(fileName);    

File file = fileName;

if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
        System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
        return;
    }

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);

if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);
```

}

```
private static File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath2){
        File dir = new File(dirPath2);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
           if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
               lastModifiedFile = files[i];
           }
        }
        return lastModifiedFile;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if your Array is correctly sorted you could do something like this :

```
File lastUpdatedFile = files[0]
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExcel\\Excel.exe",lastUpdatedFile.getAbsolutePath()).start();
```

Comment: I would not hard code the path to excel but this should work (if excel accept the parameter of course).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback slayne. I have explored more and found a solution. I will post it soon. Thank you.