# How do I sort results of File.listFiles() by creation date?

Tags: java, file, sorting, nio2

In Java Sort how do I sort results of `File.listFiles()` by creation date?

I did have:

```
files = reportFolder.listFiles(new ReportFolderFilter()));
Collections.reverse(files);
```

But this will only sort them in reverse alphabetical order not creation date.

I would like a solution that does not rely on Apache Commons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java : Sort Files based on Creation Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249822/java-sort-files-based-on-creation-date)

Comment: You seem using File (java.io) and not Path (java.nio). `nio2` tag refers to `java.nio`

Comment: @davidxxx i use both, just thought an answer using nio2 would be more likley

Comment: I think you need to take a closer look at the duplicate question. There is a version of it using Apache but the main question pretty much gives what you need - it doesn't use any libs.

Comment: @Vasan the answer below is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Collections.sort or Arrays.sort or List.sort

You can get the creation date of a file by using java nio Files. readAttributes()

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final File o1, final File o2) {
            try {
                BasicFileAttributes f1Attr = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(f1.toURI()), BasicFileAttributes.class);
                BasicFileAttributes f2Attr = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(f2.toURI()), BasicFileAttributes.class);
                return f1Attr.creationTime().compareTo(f2Attr.creationTime());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Or using Comparator.comparing:

```
Comparator<File> comparator = Comparator.comparing(file -> {
    try {
        return Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(file.toURI()), BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
});

Arrays.sort(files, comparator);
```

Comment: thx, but would be great if you actually add the creationDate logic.

Comment: listFiles returns an array. This answer isn't valid as is.

Comment: I know, it is an example of how it should be implemented. In my example 'files' is not defined, so it could be a List :) 
Either way, you can simply convert the File[] to a list by using Arrays.asList(files)

Comment: `Comparator.comparing` would be much better here

Comment: true, I have also added this option

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov thanks Comparator.comparating works for me.